# pandas df.apply function to dataframe is incredibly slow

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, performance

I want to eliminate non english words from a dataframe column but the following function has been running for a very long time without printing results.

Is there anything that I can implement in my function so that the last line of my code including `df.apply` will produce quick results ?

Keep in mind that the `dataframe` that I am using here is much smaller than the one I need help with which contains over **7000** rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nltk.corpus import brown

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['text'] = ['the fulton 5ddef', 'aerderdrdfg country grand', 'jury sdcvwefdf said']
df['length'] = [3,3,3]
def remove_words(words):  
    english_words = list(set(w.lower() for w in brown.words())) # approx 50000 words
    split=words.split()
    english_words_in_sentence = np.intersect1d(english_words, split)
    return english_words_in_sentence

# never stops running when applied to a larger dataframe
df['text_clean'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: remove_words(x))

df.head()
```

by using `numpy` I vectorized the `remove_words` function as much as possible since for loops take much longer but timing is still a big issue

Comment: `numpy` stands for *numeric Python*. It delivers very good performances when dealing with numbers. But as soon as you use Python objects, it has to constantly switch between regular Python environment and numpy one. So: *by using numpy I vectorized the remove_words function* - no you did not because you use Python objects instead of numpy specific types. Better to use plain Python here, and you could have better performances searching in sets than in lists or numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are reconstructing the list of English words for each row in the dataset, just do this once and build the function over it, also keep the `set` for efficient membership test:

```
english_words = set(w.lower() for w in brown.words())

def remove_words(text, word_list=english_words):  
    return [w for w in text.split() if w in word_list]

df['text_clean']=df['text'].apply(lambda x: remove_words(x))
```

You don't even need `apply`:

```
english_words = set(w.lower() for w in brown.words())

df['text_clean'] = [[w for w in s.split() if w in english_words]
                    for s in df['text']]
```

Output:

```
                        text  length        text_clean
0           the fulton 5ddef       3     [the, fulton]
1  aerderdrdfg country grand       3  [country, grand]
2        jury sdcvwefdf said       3      [jury, said]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["text"] = [
    "The fulton 5ddef",
    "aerderdrdfg country grand asddf lmao",
    "jury sdcvwefdf said fulton asdf",
]
df["length"] = df["text"].str.split().str.len()
english_words = np.array(list(set(w.lower() for w in brown.words())))

# get df["text"] as list of arrays
split_arr = df["text"].str.lower().str.split().to_numpy()
# flatten list of arrays
long = np.concatenate(split_arr).ravel()
# get intersection array
intersections = np.isin(long, english_words)

# filter only valid words
filtered_words = long[intersections]
# compute groups
indices = np.cumsum(df["length"])[:-1]
# split intersections according to indices
mask = np.split(intersections, indices)
# compute short indices (excluding filtered out words)
short_indices = np.cumsum([np.sum(l) for l in mask])[:-1]
# insert in df
df["text_clean"] = np.split(filtered_words, short_indices)
print(df)

                                   text  length              text_clean
0                      The fulton 5ddef       3           [the, fulton]
1  aerderdrdfg country grand asddf lmao       5  [country, grand, lmao]
2       jury sdcvwefdf said fulton asdf       5    [jury, said, fulton]
```

First we transform the df["text"] column into a numpy array and flatten it.
We filter for the words that are only in long array and not in english_words.

We compute the groups per each row, then apply these groups to the intersections array, we compute the new groups using the intersections grouped array of arrays. We use this new grouping in filtered words and put it in the df.